# How to convert a jcharArray to a char[] in c

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, ffi

I have a `jcharArray` that is passed into a C program through Java, and I need to know how to use the array in the C program. How do I convert my `jcharArray` bits into something I can use (`char bits[]`)?

I tried writing this code using JNI

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_ex_NistStatisticalTestSuite_frequency
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jcharArray bits, jint jn)
{

    printf("running frequency test");

    int     i;
    double  f, s_obs, p_value, sum, sqrt2 = 1.41421356237309504880;
    int n=jn;
    char deletethis=(char)bits[0];
    sum = 0.0;
    for ( i=0; i<n; i++ )
        sum += 2*1-1;
    s_obs = fabs(sum)/sqrt(n);
    f = s_obs/sqrt2;
    p_value = erfc(f);

    return (jint)p_value;

}
```

but it fails to compile, saying:

> ```
> frequency.c:19:2: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct _jobject’
>   char deletethis=(char)bits[0];
>   ^~~~
> frequency.c:19:28: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct _jobject’
>   char deletethis=(char)bits[0];
> ```

Comment: Could you show us your code? What have you tried? What was the result? Are you getting compile errors? Does the data not transfer correctly?

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use jni functions, there are at least two methods:

Copy a region:

```
jchar buf[10]; 
(*env)->GetCharArrayRegion(env, bits, 0, 10, buf);
```

lock a memory region in JVM, then access it and finally release:

```
jchar *carr; 
carr = (*env)->GetCharArrayElements(env, bits, NULL); 
if (carr == NULL) {
    return 0; /* exception occurred */ 
} 
//for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
//    do something with carr[i]; 
//} 
(*env)->ReleaseCharArrayElements(env, bits, carr, 0);
```

Here I assume your array is 10 elements in length. To find out number of elements in the array use `GetArrayLength` jni function.